# Trying to get the value of a node in JavaScript, but it keeps saying it's "null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, nodes

I'm currently playing around with creating lists from HTML elements. My goal is to create a list of all values in a table when you click the "page next" buttons on the table. I then have an alert pop up to tell me the value of the *first* item in the list (which should be the value of the first row in the table). However, it always comes back "null".

**Here is my JS**

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function (e) {
    var $allSerialNumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('box-electrode');
    alert('The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers.length + ' items is ' + $allSerialNumbers.item(0).nodeValue);
});
```

**Here is an example of the HTML in the table's rows I'm targeting**

```
<a href="#" class="box-electrode" value="56" title="Pack this electrode">
    <i class="fa fa-gift fa-fw text-warning"></i>
</a>
```

Currently the table has about 15 items (there is code elsewhere that creates the table from a DB), and the alert correctly says `$allSerialNumbers.length` is 15. However, it says the `nodeValue` of the first item is *null*, when it should actually say "56" in this example. (In the actual table, all the values are different).

Am I using JavaScript's nodes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as if youre using jQuery, you don't need to use `document.getElementsByClassName` (vanilla JS selector).

You can select your elements with `$('.box-electrode')`.

Another thing: an anchor (`<a>`) element doesn't have a `value` attribute. Either if you try to get it with jQuery's `.val()`, you won't get it, because it's not in the specification.

If you want to set custom attributes, you can use `data-` attributes. Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="box-electrode" data-value="56" title="Pack this electrode">
    <i class="fa fa-gift fa-fw text-warning"></i>
</a>
```

**jQuery solution:**

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function (e) {
    var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');
    alert('The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers.length + ' items is ' + $allSerialNumbers.first().attr('data-value'));
});
```

- [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) get the first element in a  jQuery Object.
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) get the value of a specified node attribute.

**Vanilla JS:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("page-link")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var $allSerialNumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('box-electrode');

    alert(
    'The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers.length + ' items is' +
    ' data-value: ' + $allSerialNumbers[0].getAttribute('data-value') +
    ', title: ' + $allSerialNumbers[0].title
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, variables starting with $ are by convention used for jquery objects. $allSerialNumbers is a node element, not a jquery object.

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function (e) {
     var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');
     alert('The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers.length + ' items is ' + $allSerialNumbers[0].text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jquery, why not just do:

```
var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');

alert('The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers.length + ' items is ' + $allSerialNumbers[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function (e) {
    var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode'),
          $targetVal =  $(e.target).attr('data-value');
    alert('The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers + ' items is ' + $targetVal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do just attributes to get the attribute "value" and then just access it's value with .value, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function (e) {
    var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');
    alert('The first in the list of ' + $allSerialNumbers.length + ' items is ' + $allSerialNumbers[0].attributes["value"].value);
});
```

Since you are using jquery, no need to do .getElements..

Here you have a working fiddler in case you want to try other options with this same example: https://jsfiddle.net/spilafis/ufp4bz80/10